# Trace kernel scheduling and memory operations under Windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading, debugging, kernel, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to trace scheduled threads under Windows? In other words I want to know the sequence of processes that are executed on a CPU and the time each process/thread was switched in. A related need is to understand memory allocations because the kernel will periodically stop what it is doing and fool around with memory, so along with seeing the thread context scheduling I would also want to see other, non-application, house-keeping threads that the kernel is scheduling. Is this possible?

For background on this problem please see the paper:

LaRosa, Christopher, Li Xiong, and Ken Mandelberg. "Frequent pattern mining for kernel trace data." Proceedings of the 2008 ACM symposium on applied computing. ACM, 2008.

Comment: In general, such events happen faster than you could output them.  Just outputting such events would cause a cascade of further events, same with memory-management.  Not sure what you mean by 'kernel will periodically stop what it is doing and fool around with memory'.

Comment: @Martin James The scheduler does not just schedule user threads, it schedules kernel threads and driver threads. One of the main such threads is the kernel's internal memory manager that periodically re-arranges memory. I would like to see scheduling of all threads including these house keeping threads. Obviously, any such trace facility would have to be implemented directly by the scheduler.